# Why is image.astype(uint8) different from np.clip(image.astype(uint32), 0, 255) in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, noise, unsigned-integer

I am a bit confused about a behavior of my code.

I have an `image` tensor with values in range [0, 255] to which I have added some Gaussian noise so that the resulting tensor has values in larger and now continuous range, e.g. ca. [-253.234, 581.613].

This tensor should then be visualized via `plt.imshow(...)`.

For this and other purposes, I would like to cast the tensor to a `uint` type. However, I encountered some weird differences between the following approaches and I would like to identify the *right* approach:

1. `plt.imshow(image.astype(np.uint32))`
2. `plt.imshow(image.astype(np.uint8))`
3. `plt.imshow(np.clip(image.astype(np.uint32), 0, 255))`

Approach (1) leads to the expected `"Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)."` warning. And I assume that this image is then clipped like `np.clip` to values in the range [0, 255].

Approaches (2) and (3) lead to values in range [0, 255] so no exception is thrown but their mean values differ.

Approaches (1) and (3) lead to the same visualization, while (2) leads to a different image (e.g. slightly darker and more noisy).

I am currently clueless about why this happens. Is converting to `uint32` and then clipping different from converting to `uint8` in the first place?

Comment: Yep, it is different. Try `np.uint8(256)`and see if that result is what you'd expect. It is not the same as clipping `np.uint32` between `(0, 255)`

Comment: I suspect that what you do is not what you intend to. Mapping to unsigned integer a signed range will result in the negative values wrapping around. What once was Gaussian noise, is now God-knows noise. I guess what you want to do is some rescaling instead, e.g. `((image - np.min(image)) / np.ptp(image) * 255).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: Approaches (1) and (3) lead to the same visualization because `matplotlib` is clipping for you in (1). (2) and (3) are fundamentally different mathematical operations. (2) is equivalent to `int(image % MAX_UINT8)` while (3) is `clip(image % MAX_UINT32, 0, 255)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful replies. This all makes total sense! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have any negative values in the image, then casting to uint32 is or uint8 will create different results.